# How to typecast string to date object In hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, hstore

typecast string object to date in hstore

I have done typecast for string like this 
`Project.where("(form_data -> '12')::int > 2")` it is working fine but unable to typecast it for date like `Project.where("(form_data -> '12-13-10-2016')::date > 22-102016")`.

it give me error 
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  schema "date" does not exist`

Comment: Yes updated but why it don't allow to typecast date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for the question I asked here is the solutions

`Project.where("(form_data -> '22-10-2014')::date > to_date('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY')")`

I referred [this](http://%20postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: I referred this link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html